# Pyqt5 functions delaying events when paired with a driver call

Tags: python, pyqt5, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently trying to execute a function based on a button click that runs several events such as label changes and stopping a mediaplayer before opening a webdriver, but for some reason only one of the events executes and the others are ignored until after. In this block of code the only thing that happens priar to the driver opening is the player stop event. The video hide and label text change does not execute until after the driver is launched despite being written before it.

```
def initiateclick(self):
        global driver
        self.player.stop()
        self.video.hide()
        self.userInfo.setText("Checking to see if you are already logged in.")
        #Launch the first instance and check for login
        driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=options)
        driver.get('https://google.com/')
```

Comment: The driver loading blocks the event queue, so widgets cannot be properly updated with the new state. If you don't need the selenium driver on the main thread, move it to a QThread.

Comment: It's very odd, somethings work and others do not. For instance I can add print commands all day and they all fire before the driver. If I delete the player stop the video hide still executes afterwards regardless. Idk why the player stop magically works but not the video hide or the set text... I'm vastly confused.

Comment: A print command is a completely different thing than something related with the event loop, and the multimedia API, which is managed in a different thread with its own event loop. It seems you don't know a lot on the matter, so I suggest you to do some research about threading in python, how the GIL works and what is event driven programming.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. Now I'm running it on a workerthread and executed the rest upon it's completion.